# Validator Error Message makes submit button disappear from page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

When I click on the **submit button** or type it makes the button **disappear** from the page, and the **form** is **pushed** **up** by the error message.

**How can I style the error message to prevent the submit button from disappearing and pushing the form "up"?**

Here's the code and the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/psbq8vkj/1/

**CSS:**

```
.error-class {
    color:red;  z-index:300; font-size:25px; 
}


.guestlistfield.error-class {
   position:relative; margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;
}




input.error-class { border:3px solid red;}

input.error-class:focus { border:3px solid #f90;}

.valid-class {
    color:black;
}

.emailaddress:focus, textarea:focus {
    border:3px solid #f90;
}



@media (min-width:765px) { 
    .guestlist
    {
        overflow: hidden;
         width:100%; max-width:730px; margin-top:20px;
         height:120px; display:inline-block;
    }


    .guestlist .title h2
    {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }



}

@media (max-width:764px) { 
    .guestlist
    {
        overflow: hidden;
     width:100%; min-width:200px;
         height:120px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-bottom:10px;
        text-align:left;
    }


    .guestlist .title h2
    {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }


}


@media (min-width:765px) { 
    .guestlist2
    {
    overflow: hidden;
         width:100%; 
         height:120px; display:inline-block;
    }


    .guestlist2 .title h2
    {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
}

@media (max-width:764px) { 
.guestlist2
    {
        overflow: hidden;
     width:100%; 
         height:90px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-bottom:10px;   
        text-align:left;
    }



    .guestlist2 .title h2
    {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
}



                .guestlistfield
            {
                position: relative;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                border: 0;
                background: #fff;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
                width:98%; position:relative;
                border-radius: 0.50em; 
                margin: 1em 0em; display:inline-block;
                padding: 1.50em 1em; padding-right:90px; 
                box-shadow: inset 0 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
                border: solid 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
                font-size: 1em;
                outline: none;
            }








        form input.guestlistfield:enabled,
            form select:enabled,
            form textarea:enabled
{

    background:#fff;

}





                form textarea
                {
                    min-height: 12em;
                }
ff
                form .formerize-placeholder
                {
                    color: #555 !important;
                }

                form ::-webkit-input-placeholder
                {
                    color: #555 !important;
                }

                form :-moz-placeholder
                {
                    color: #555 !important;
                }

                form ::-moz-placeholder
                {
                    color: #555 !important;
                }

                form :-ms-input-placeholder
                {
                    color: #555 !important;
                }

                form ::-moz-focus-inner
                {
                    border: 0;
                }



/* Button Style */


    .button
    {
        display: inline-block; background:transparent;
        padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
        line-height:3.7em; position:relative;
        text-decoration: none; 
         border-left: solid #F90 4px; height:55px;
        font-weight:600;  float: right; line-height:3px;
        font-size:1em;  right:10px; border-right:none; border-top:none; border-bottom:none;
        color:#787878; top:-75px; vertical-align:center; font-size:bolder;
    }

        .button:focus
    {
        display: inline-block; background:transparent;
        padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
        line-height:3.7em; position:relative;
        text-decoration: none; 
         border-left: solid #F90 4px; height:55px;
        font-weight:600;  float: right; line-height:3px;
        font-size:1em;  right:10px; border-right:none; border-top:none; border-bottom:none;
        color:#787878; top:-75px; vertical-align:center; font-size:bolder;
    }




.button:hover
    {
        color:#000; border-left: solid #39F 4px;
    }




#updates 
    { 

        background:rgba(51, 153, 255, 0.7); width:100vw; left:0;
    }



    @media (max-width:280px) { 
.signuptitle {font-size:15px; color:#fff; margin-top:50px;}

    }


    @media (min-width:281px) {


    .signuptitle {font-size:20px; color:#fff; text-shadow:1px 1px #000; margin-top:50px;}   
    }


    @media (min-width: 659px){
    .signuptitle {font-size:30px; color:#fff; text-shadow:2px 2px #000; margin-top:50px;}   

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
            <div id="updates" class="container-fluid">

                <center>
                <div class="title">

       <br /><span class="signuptitle">Sign up to our daily newsletter.</span>  <br /></div>

  <div class="guestlist">
<form class="guestlist-form" action="email.php" method="post"> 
    <input name="emailaddress" type="text" title="Enter Email Address" class="guestlistfield" placeholder="Enter your Email" /> 
   <input class="button" title="Join" type="submit" value="Sign up">
</form>
</div>

                    </center>
                <br> <br>
  </div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".guestlist-form").validate({
    errorClass: "error-class",
    validClass: "valid-class",  
    rules: {
            emailaddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
    },

    messages: {

    emailaddress: {
                required: "Please enter your full email address."           
            }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button disapear because of the z-index of the .error-class.

First, a space is missing between .guestlist-form and .error-class in your jsfiddle, so the z-index was not applied (Line 6 in jsfiddle)

```
.guestlist-form .error-class {
    color:red;  z-index:1;
}
```

And you can add this to set the z-index for the submit button

```
.guestlist-form .button {
  z-index:2;
}
```

For the form pushing up, it's because the submit button have `top: -75px;` and you have put `margin:0 auto;` to the `.guestlistfield` class when there are an error. Remove the margin and the form will no longer pushing up. (Line 10 in jsfiddle)

```
.guestlistfield.error-class {
   position:relative; /*margin:0 auto;*/ display:inline-block;
}
```

Finally, I suggest you to increase the height of the `.guestlist` class, because some of the text will be hidden.

Comment: I completely overlooked the z-index factor, thanks for your help. You're the best!

Comment: Hey @garric15, I just found another bug in the code you suggested to use, when you resize the window and receive an error message it pushes the submit button to the bottom.

Comment: You can create a new div **below** the form and using the [errorPlacement](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to put the error message in this div :  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcnmkyrj/1/)

Comment: Hi, Garric. The code you provided has another major flaw the error message doesnt disappear when I enter a correct email address. Here's my a link to my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339205/validation-error-message-wont-hide-when-valid

Comment: You have to add the `success` attribute to the validation : [Answer from your post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339205/validation-error-message-wont-hide-when-valid/36343183#36343183)

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the "z-index:300;" from .error-class and added a "margin-bottom:2.5%;" to your "emailaddress" input.

```
<input name="emailaddress" type="text" title="Enter Email Address" class="guestlistfield" placeholder="Enter your Email" style="margin-bottom: 2.5%;" />
```

This way, the buttom keeps its place when the submit error occours.